# I have to filter data between two dates in mean stack

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

im getting data from mongodb using angularjs and nodejs and storing into one variable i want to filer date between two dates start date and end date and push into one array any one help me

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope,$http){

 - List item


$http.get('/api')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.recards = data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log('hello');
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);

        });
     }
```

Comment: please any one can help me on my issue

Comment: The `.success` method is deprecated and removed from AngularJS V1.6